# Is the sum of factorials of first $n$ natural numbers ever a perfect cube?

Tags: summation, factorial

If $S_n = 1! + 2! + 3! + \dots + n!$, is there any term in $S_n$ which is a perfect cube or out of $S_1$, $S_2$, $S_3$, $\dots S_n$ is there any term which is a perfect cube, where $n$ is any natural number.

Comment: I have tried solving this problem by calculating last 2 digits in sum of factorial series and found that it is always coming out to be 13 for n>10 , but i cannot infer anything from this..

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese ,Cubes of Numbers 17, 117, 217 ....have 13 as its last two digits..

Comment: That is a good idea.  Unfortunately, $17^3$ ends in $13$.  It takes three digits to succeed.  If this works for you, you could answer your own question.

Comment: Yeah, I realised my mistake a little too late.

Comment: @RossMillikan, i can also calculate the last three digits for n>15, but how to proceed after that..??

Comment: One more thing if this sum ever a perfect cube then it would be a perfect cube of number having its unit digit 7, because unit digit in that case would be 3..

Comment: It is not as simple as I thought.  It stabilizes at 313, but 217^3 ends in 313.  So now we know that if $n \gt 15, n=217+1000k$ for some $k$  I think there must be some other base than 10 that will work for this.

Comment: Actually it is 313+1000k for n>15

Comment: The sum is 313+1000k, but the cube root (if it existed) would be 217+1000k'

Comment: My answer is essentially your idea of checking the last digits, but in a base that works.  I tried powers of $2$ a bit, but that didn't work, then the next prime hit the jackpot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All factorials above $8!$ have a factor of $27$ and $S_8 \equiv 9 \pmod {27}$  As there is no solution to $k^3 \equiv 9 \pmod {27}$, we cannot have $n \ge 9$.  Then just checking $n$ up through $8$, only $S_1=1$ is a perfect cube.

Comment: Not getting you please explain this in a little more detail

Comment: Got your idea thanks @Ross Millikan

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, we can also use $\pmod{7}$ to prove that $1!+2!+3!+\cdots+n!$ is never a perfect cube $\forall n\geq2$.

Note that $7\mid n!$ if $n\geq7$, so whenever $n\geq6$, then  $1!+2!+3!+4!+5!+6!\equiv5\pmod{7}$.

But all perfect cubes are either equal to $0,\pm1\pmod{7}$, so $1!+2!+3!+\cdots n!$ isn’t a perfect cube if $n\geq6$.

We can check the values of $n$ between $2$ to $6$ and by brute force, we see that the sum is not a perfect cube.

Bonus:

Note that $11\mid1!+2!+3!+\cdots+10!$, so the sum(if $n\geq10$) is divisible by $11$, and so, the sum(if $n\geq21$) must be divisible by $121$ in order to be a perfect cube.

In this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/117847/proving-that-sum-limits-i-1k-i-ne-n2-for-any-n?noredirect=1&lq=1), it is said that $11^{2}\mid n!$ if $n!\geq22$, but because $1!+2!+3!+\cdots+21!\not\equiv0\pmod{11^{2}}$, then the sum is not divisible by $11^{2}$, and as a result, not a perfect cube.