# Need help with Factorial Sums!

Tags: elementary-number-theory, factorial

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to prove that the number $1!+2!+3!+\dots+n!$ is never square?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33863/how-to-prove-that-the-number-123-n-is-never-square)

Show that the sum $$\sum_{k=1}^nk!\neq m^2$$for any integer $m$, for $n\geq4$.

Comment: Using $m^2 \equiv 0,1,4 (\mathrm{mod}\;5)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At $4$ the sum is $33$. Beyond $4$, every new term is divisible by $5$. So at $4$ or beyond, the sum is $\equiv 3\pmod{5}$. Nothing congruent to $3$ modulo $5$ can be a perfect square.