# $1!+2!+3!+4!+5!+...+n!$ is a square of an integer

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, factorial

At what n is the number $1!+2!+3!+4!+...+n!$ a square of another integer number?
All in all I have found $2$ values: $1$ and $3$. I think they are the only ones, but the only thing left is to prove it. How?

Comment: Consider it modulo $5$.

Comment: @DanielFischer iam much into this problem,can someone show without modulo?

Comment: Also related: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/33863/9464

Comment: those are the same questions!

Answer (score 13):

Let $1!+2!+3!+\cdots \cdots +n! = y^2$

$\star$ if $n=1\;,$ then $1=y^2$ (True)

$\star$ if $n=2\;,$ then $1+2=3=y^2$ (False)

$\star$ if $n=3,$ then $1+2+6=9=y^2$ (True)

$\star$ if $n=4,$ then $1+2+6+24=33=y^2$(False)

for $n\geq 5,$ then  L .H .S end with $3$ and we now that square of any integer does not have last digit $3$

so we have only $n=1,n=3$ for which $y^2$ is a perfect square quantity

Comment: Along the lines of Daniel's comment, this amounts to "considering it modulo 10".

Comment: yes i have also use daniel hint her.

Comment: How can you say "for $n\geq 5,$ then  L .H .S end with $3$"?

Comment: @Help , since for $n\geq 5$, $10 | n!$ so $n!$ ends in a 0, so the sum will end in a 3, the last digit of $1! + 2! + 3! + 4! $.

Comment: How can I prove that a square does not have last digit 3?

Comment: @idliketodothis take it mod 5...

Comment: @idliketodothis you can prove it using modular arithmetic, but if you don't know that, then you can make a simple check-by-check case using the last digit of number.

Comment: @idliketodothis If $y$ ends in $1$, $y^2$ ends in $1$. If $y$ ends in $2$, $y^2$ ends in $4$. If $y$ ends in $3$, $y^2$ ends in $9$. If $y$ ends in $4$, $y^2$ ends in $6$. Etcetera. You'll see that there's no possible value of $y$ for which $y^2$ ends in $3$.

Comment: @idliketodothis In fact, squares can only end in the digits $0$, $1$, $4$, $5$, $6$, or $9$.